# ¿Cómo se crea el operador de sintaxis?

Tags: javascript, sintaxis

Si tengo una función que busca elementos por clase asi:

```
function buscarClase(clase){
    return Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(clase.toString()));
}
```

Entonces para buscar la clase, tan sólo haría:

```
buscarClase("m");
```

Todo bien, pero ¿Cómo puedo realizar para cambiar la forma de llamar a la función, como Jquery lo hace? Más claramente me refiero al operador.

En jquery para buscar una id sería:

```
 $("#m")
```

Entonces, ¿Cómo podría crear un operador para llamar a mi función? por ejemplo:

```
º('#m');
```

Intentando revisar el código de ***Jquery(desminifizado)***, he visto funciones, expresiones regulares pero es muchísimo código y no logro entender.

Comment: Ah no, eso no se puede, es parte del intérprete de Javascript, todo lo que esté en corchetes se refiere a una posición en un arreglo o a una llave de un objeto

Comment: Algo que estás confundiendo, es que `$` no es un operador, no es un elemento especial de jQuery ni mucho menos,`$` es solamente una variable que almacena una referencia a la función jQuery de tal forma que hacer `$('#m')` es lo mismo que `jQuery('#m')`, por eso la respuesta de ArtEze responde a tu pregunta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que hace jQuery, de un modo muy simplificado y sin usar expresiones regulares es lo siguiente:

```js
function $$(arg1) {
    debugger;
    if (arg1.charAt(0)=='#') {
      return [document.getElementById(arg1.substr(1))];
    }
    
    if (arg1.charAt(0)=='.') {
      return Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(arg1.substr(1)));
    }
    
    return Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName(arg1));
    
}

console.log($$('label'))
console.log($$('.hola'))
console.log($$('#dos'))
```

```html
<label class="hola">texto</label>
<label class="hola" id="dos">texto2</label>
<label class="hola2">texto3</label>
```

JQuery no devuelve un simple array, sino una clase propia que envuelve a una lista de elementos añadiendo muchas funciones, y acepta muchas más cosas como parámetros, pero para ver todo lo que añade jQuery podemos empezar por el código original en su [primera versión (la más sencilla)](https://genius.it/12258874/johnresig.com/files/jquery-original.html) pero eso da [para un libro](https://www.manning.com/books/secrets-of-the-javascript-ninja-second-edition)